# The common language runtime could not be loaded when opening a published VSTO Excel Workbook

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, deployment, vsto

I have published an Excel Workbook VSTO project to a network shared location using Visual Studio 2010 and the "Publish" Menu in the solution's properties.

I set the Publish Folder location & The Installation Folder URL to be the same UNC path.

The prerequisites are setup as shown in the below screenshots, I believe I have added more than enough but I can't be sure.

[image: VSTO Prerequisites 1]

[image: VSTO Prerequisites 2]

Using another person's machine who doesn't have .NET or Visual Studio installed; I asked them to copy the Workbook so I could test whether it would run and install the relevant dependencies.

They received an error of "The common language runtime could not be loaded... Contact an administrator"

I have not tried the relevant setup.exe because the network administrators do not allow running of executables, the user wants to share this file to multiple users so I was expecting this to work just by opening the file.. but it seems that in either case it's probably not going to work.

Does anyone know if this issue would be related to not having administrator privileges? or if I am missing a prerequisite?

The error initially looks to me like it could not install the .NET framework prerequisites.

Unfortunately this is a very slow process because of going back and forth to this other user as I don't have a virtual machine with access to the network location.

NOTE: I have also tried the "Download prerequisites from the same location as my location" and got the same error.

Comment: In my experience, you need admin privileges to install .NET and the VSTO runtime.  However, it normally gives an error explicitly saying something about Admin Rights, not what you described.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone else getting this.

In my case all users already had .NET 4.0 installed.

They did NOT have the VSTO4 runtime installed and the solution was using features of the VSTO runtime.

The VSTO4 runtime requires admin access to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

did you use VS 2012 to publish this? Not sure but when publishing a VSTO VS2010 is the only thing that has worked for me.  Also,

Comment: Yea, I used VS 2010 and Excel 2007.